# Sticky footer with a height 100%-body -> possible without javascript?

Tags: css, height, footer, sticky

I have a problem concerning a layout I have to create. The upper layout is the one I currently have. When the Main-div expands by adding content to it, the footer's vertical position increases, which is what I want. But when there's only little content in main, there's space between the footer and the screen's lower border, which is ugly ;) I tried to place the footer sticky to the bottom. The result: when adding much content to main, the footer lies above the main div and its content :( It's a little bit hard to explain, but I think you know, what I mean.

What I want to accomplish is the lower layout. The main div should be "screen.height - header.height - footer.height".

Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Bye The_Unknown

[image: example image]

Comment: If you could try using something like CSS `position: static` to maintain a "sticky" position. It'd probably be better though if you had a fixed footer height, otherwise your footer would scroll.

Comment: SO wouldn't let me post a short answer below, so I'll do it here. No.

Comment: @War10ck: Oh, the footer it fixed in its height, if that helps.

Comment: You're asking for a dynamic change in the layout of the page. CSS doesn't allow for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
   html,body {
      height:100%
   }

   #wrapper {
     min-height:100%;
     margin-bottom:-150px; /* negative total computed height of footer */
   }

   #footer_padding {
     height:150px; /* total computed height of footer */
   }

   #footer {
     height:100px;
     margin-top:50px;
   }
</style>    


<div id="wrapper">

   <div>some content...</div>

   <div id="footer_padding"></div>

</div>

<div id="footer"></div>
```